# Javascript: Basic native form validation - can't validate more than one criterion

Tags: javascript, validation

trying to learn how to validate form input.

The inputs need to:
1 - Not be empty.
2 - Only contain alphabetic characters (no digits).

When I test (I've only focused on first name input field for now) it will give the correct error message **if I leave it blank**. But, if I but **digits** in the field it will submit instead of displaying error message.

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<form id="frm1">
   <fieldset id="controls">
    <div>
      <label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
       <input type="text" id="firstname">
        <span id="errFname" class="errmsg">&#42 You must enter a first name</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <label for="lastname">Last Name: </label>
       <input type="text" id="lastname">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
    function checkForm(){


    document.getElementById("frm1").onsubmit=function() {


        //Validate first name: Required, Alphabetic (no numbers)
        if(document.getElementById("firstname").value === "") {

            document.getElementById("errFname").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("firstname").focus();

            return false;

        }   else {

            return true;
        }//close if


        var alphaRegEx = /[a-zA-Z]/;
        var alphafname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;

        //check if first name has any digits
        if (!alphaRegEx.test(alphafname)){

            document.getElementById("errFname").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("firstname").value="";
            document.getElementById("firstname").focus();

            return false;

        }   else {

            return true;

        }//close if


    }//close function

    return false;

}//close function (checkForm)


window.onload=checkForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning inside each `if` block and that is making the whole `submit` callback to return.

You should create a variable and return only at the end. Something like this:

```
function checkForm(){


document.getElementById("frm1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    var errors = [];

    //Validate first name: Required, Alphabetic (no numbers)
    if(document.getElementById("firstname").value === "") {

        document.getElementById("errFname").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("firstname").focus();

        errors.push("required");

    }


    var alphaRegEx = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    var alphafname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;

    //check if first name has any digits
    if (!alphaRegEx.test(alphafname) && errors.length === 0){

        document.getElementById("errFname").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("firstname").value="";
        document.getElementById("firstname").focus();

        errors.push("numeric");

    }
    //If you want, you can do something with your errors, if not, just return
    //You should rethink about handling all errors here showing/hiding messages, etc.
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    return true;


});//close function

}//close function (checkForm)
```

Comment: with this solution the error message flashes on screen for a split second. form resets. How woud I make it so that it only resets when all the validation is correct?

Comment: What do you mean with "resets"? It is submitted? If so, check my new solution.

Comment: I mean if I put an invalid value in the input field, then the error message displays but only or a split seond and then the input form is empty again. So I'm guessing it is submitting and resetting the form?

Comment: Oh, i see, the problem is because both validations are running. Let me re-write my solution.

Comment: ok brilliant I see now. So passing the preventDefault method to the event listener stops the form from submitting if there are errors..?

Comment: Yup. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault